# How extjs is browser independent

Tags: extjs

I have heard that EXTJS is a browser independent javascript library. How does extjs make itself browser independent? When I open up the library classes, I do not see any code like :
if (IE)//do this;
else if (FF) // do something else;

Is my understanding correct that extjs is browser independent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to sha's point, I'm aware that ExtJS uses conditional checks for browser features and selects whether to use things like images, or css for particular visual effects.

Two examples of this would be that it manages to produce rounded corners on it's widgets in IE6 via images, but in anything which supports it, it will use 'border-radius' in CSS.

This is also true with gradients in widgets, which are rendered as images in older browsers, but use CSS3 gradients where supported.

As a rule, from what I've seen, ExtJS uses 'feature detection' to work out what your current browser supports and responds appropriately. A further example of this would be it's charting classes, which render as SVG if supported, or VML on older browsers.

There are some classes in ExtJS you can use to perform feature detection if you wish to do anything specific outside of it's in built in actions too. I'd imagine it uses these under the hood to make decisions about what to render.

That aside, it should be noted that every now and again, you can notice odd discrepancies between browser versions, usually annoying little visual effects, like a scrollbar being present in one browser an not in another, this could however just be a symptom of other code, but I know we've seen a few little quirks from time to time when testing accross IE8, IE9 and Chrome for example.

Answer (score 4):

It is browser independent. As far as I know they have some different CSS definitions for different browsers. If you want to see is there any difference in the JS code you will have to look deeper - probably at some ExtJs core files.

We've been using it so far on IE, FF, Chrome, Safari, Mobile Safari etc.